# Setup variable in mocha suite before each test?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I would like to setup some variables first, before executing the test,
and I found this solution, [Running Mocha setup before each suite rather than before each test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107027/running-mocha-setup-before-each-suite-rather-than-before-each-test)

But, I dont know how can I pass the variable into my callback, they way I did I will get undefined

```
makeSuite('hello', (context) => {
    it('should return', () => {
        assert.strictEqual(1, 1)
    })
})
makeSuite('world', (context) => {
    it('should return', () => {
        console.log(context) // undefined
        assert.strictEqual(1, 1)
    })
})

function makeSuite(name: string, cb: (context: any) => any) {
    let age: string;
    describe(name, () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            age = '123'
        })

        cb(age);
    })
}
```

The reason why I want to pass the variable into the callback because, I will have many private variables that requires to setup at `beforeEach` hook, and I dont want to repeat my code for all the tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The callbacks passed to `describe` are called immediately but your `beforeEach` hook is called *later* when the test executes. So when `cb(age)` is called, `age` has for value `undefined`. `age` is later set to `"123"` but `cb` has already gotten its copy of the value earlier so it has no effect. In order for `cb` to see the change you'd have to pass a reference to an object that you then mutate. Something like this:

```
makeSuite('world', (context) => {
    it('should return', () => {
        console.log(context.age)
    })
})

function makeSuite(name, cb) {
    describe(name, () => {
        let context = {
            age: undefined,
        };
        beforeEach(() => {
            context.age = '123';
        });

        cb(context);
    });
}
```

(I've removed the TypeScript type annotations so that it runs as pure JavaScript. The annotations are not crucial to solving the problem anyway.)

Comment: very smart solution! ;), i did found another way, is to inject into the `mocha context`, but i dont think this is a good practice!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, which is to inject the variable into `mocha context`

```
makeSuite('world', function() {
    it('should return', function() {
        // read the variable as shown below
        console.log((this as any).age); // 123
    })
})

function makeSuite(name: string, cb: () => any) {
    describe(name, function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            // inject the desired variable into the mocha context
            (this as any).age = 123;
        })

        cb();
    })
}
```

But, I dont think is a good practise of injecting the variable into the mocha context, the answer provided by @Louis would be better solution

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of messing with `this` because it is provided by Mocha and contains parts of its public API and some private values. A lot of times adding something to `this` is going to work but one day a new version of Mocha may come out that clashes with the variable you chose. Right now setting `this.timeout` or `this.retries`, for instance, would overwrite Mocha's own functions.

Answer (score 0):

I started with what @Louis was doing but then found it was better (in my situation) to make the function around it. That way, I could toggle the after and before actions. I also needed the before, after, and it to be asynchronous.

```
function itWithSetup(name, callback, doBefore = true, doAfter = true) {

  let context = null;
  if (doBefore) {
    before(async () => {
     context = await getContext();
    });
  }
  it(name, async () => {
    await callback(context);
  });
  if (doAfter) {
    after(async () => {
      await clearContext();
    });
  }
}

describe("test with context", () => {

  itWithSetup("unit test", async (message) => {

    await testWithContext(context, otherConditions);

  }, true, true);
});
```