# Using mocha Shared Behaviours with async before

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

Context: Given https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours I want to be able to reuse test blocks using async before. For example:

```
describe('test', () => {
  let beforeStuff
  before('something', async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let wait = setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(wait)
        beforeStuff = 'something_else'
        resolve('There is something')
      }, 200)
    })
  })

  reusableIts(beforeStuff)
})

function reusableIts(varValue) {
  it('testBlock', () => {console.log(`Value of var is $varValue`)})
}
```

Question: Is there any way to make the shared behavior accept parameters and work async as at the moment the above example yields

> Value of var is undefined

Notes: I would assume that assigning a promise to **var** and resolving it afterwards in **before**, waiting for it in **reusable**(while making it async) would be an option, but that's really messy and I would prefer something else, if, of course, there is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer a bit later and is really good documented here: [Setup variable in mocha suite before each test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412568/setup-variable-in-mocha-suite-before-each-test)

Basically you need a context object:

```
describe('test', () => {
  let context = {
      beforeStuff: undefined
  }
  before('something', async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let wait = setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(wait)
        context.beforeStuff = 'something_else'
        resolve('There is something')
      }, 200)
    })
  })

  reusableIts(context)
})

function reusableIts(context) {
  it('testBlock', () => {console.log(`Value of var is ${context.beforeStuff}`)})
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you made it simpler.
Worth mentioning the `setTimeout` is just to prove the concept, any `Promise` there will work.
The trick is save everything inside the "context" and not change it's reference, simple and brilliant.